# Unable to retrieve value of 'totalResults' from JSON output

Tags: android, json, xml, android-studio, android-asynctask

Here is JSON output I'm getting:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 38,
  "articles": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Firstpost.com"
      },
      "author": null,
      "title": "Astronaut with blood clot on ISS gets successfully treated by doctor on Earth - Firstpost",
      "description": "The ISS had a limited supply of blood thinners that they had to make do with till the next re-supply mission.",
      "url": "https://www.firstpost.com/tech/science/astronaut-with-blood-clot-on-iss-gets-successfully-treated-by-doctor-on-earth-7866961.html",
      "urlToImage": "https://images.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ISS_NASA.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2020-01-06T10:24:12Z",
      "content": "tech2 News StaffJan 06, 2020 15:54:12 IST\r\nHow on Earth does someone treat a life-threatening blood clot when you're in space? Dr Stephan Moll at the University of North Carolina School of Medicine a doctor and clotting expert can tell you how.\r\nIn an unprece… [+3928 chars]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's `Profile.java`:

```
public class Profile {

    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    @Expose
    private String imageUrl;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("totalResults")
    @Expose
    private int totalResults;

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(int totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Here's the `AsyncTask` for retrieving the data:

```
class DownloadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String xml = "";

            String urlParameters = "";
            xml = Function.excuteGet("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey="+API_KEY, urlParameters);
            return xml;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String xml) {

            if (xml != null) {
                if (xml.length() > 10) { // Just checking if not empty

                    Log.d("xml", xml);

                    for (final Profile profile : Utils.loadProfiles(getBaseContext(), xml)) {
                        PROGRESS_COUNT = profile.getTotalResults();
                        Log.d("PROGRESS_COUNT", String.valueOf(PROGRESS_COUNT));
                        storiesProgressView.setStoriesCount(PROGRESS_COUNT);
                        storiesProgressView.setStoryDuration(3000L);
                        storiesProgressView.startStories();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No news found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("xml", "Null");
            }
        }

    }
```

Here's `Utils.java`:

```
public class Utils {

    private static final String TAG = "Utils";

    public static List<Profile> loadProfiles(Context context, String xml) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(xml);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("articles");
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = builder.create();
            List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Profile profile = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getString(i), Profile.class);
                profileList.add(profile);
            }
            return profileList;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see in the JSON output above, `totalResults` is `38` but in the log in the AsyncTask class, it is showing `D/PROGRESS_COUNT: 0`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post code for `Utils.loadProfiles(getBaseContext(), xml)` and move this line out of for loop. No need to do same task over and over again. Do once and keep in a variable to be used in for loop.

Comment: You `json` response is not aligned with your `model`. You have to update your `model`.

Comment: @rohit5k2 added, please check

Comment: You have never set the value of it. How do you expect to find it? You are only adding whats inside articles array. "status" and "totalResults" are outside of that array.

Comment: @rohit5k2 yes, I got it. Please help me with it!

Comment: What is the output of line `Log.d("xml", xml);`

Comment: simply add the value using `setTotalResults` inside for loop for every profile (if you want the value in each of them). Fetch the value from `jsonResponse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option - 1:** update your code to include `totalResults` in each of `Profile`. Check below:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(xml);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("articles");

// parse the total result
int totalResults = jsonResponse.optInt("totalResults");

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    Profile profile = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getString(i), Profile.class);

    // set totalResults to each profile
    profile.setTotalResults(totalResults);

    profileList.add(profile);
}

return profileList;
```

**Option - 2:** Update your model like below to match with your `json` response and parse it.

**Article.java:**

```
public class Article {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("totalResults")
    @Expose
    private int totalResults;

    @SerializedName("articles")
    @Expose
    private List<Profile> articles;

    // getter-setter
}
```

**Profile.java:**

```
public class Profile {

    @SerializedName("urlToImage")
    @Expose
    private String imageUrl;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    // getter-setter
}
```

And then parse your `json` like below:

```
Article article = gson.fromJson(xml, Article.class);
```